# Tag search should de-accent, not drop accented characters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

When creating a tag with an accent, the accent is automatically converted to an un-accented character.  Example:

> *número* → [numero](/questions/tagged/numero)

However, the same conversion does not happen when searching for a tag. Instead, when you enter `[número]` in the search box, it is converted to `[nmero]`. This should be made to be more consistent.

Comment: To make this question easier to find by searching let me include these terms in this comment: "accent normalization", "accent stripping", "diacritic normalization", "diacritic stripping".

Comment: @hippietrail unfortunately that doesn't work for in-site search...does for google though

Comment: Oh I meant Google. I rarely use the site's own search since it's not as good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah sure, this sounds like reasonable behavior to match up...starting with the next build we'll do the "normal" character replacement inside tags, rather than stripping it.