# How do I rename a tag to include non-English characters?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, moderator-tools, localization

In response to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags/135955?noredirect=1#comment792449_135955) I decided it was appropriate to re-spell some of our tags over at [Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) to use proper accent marks.  However, it doesn't appear to be working.

When I enter this:

> [image]

The result is this:

> [image]

The accented `ó` is turned into a non-accented `o`, and the counts are all off.  It's hard to spell out the exact bug here, since I don't know the intended behavior, but it's clearly not doing *something* right.

Comment: Please try again for me

Comment: @MarcGravell: Hey, it works now! Thanks :D

Comment: @MarcGravell: Can we get international tags enabled on meta.spanish.stackoverflow.com? The use of such tags in meta confuses the markup engine as seen [here](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1408/12), but works on the main site, so I'm guessing these tags just aren't (fully?) enabled on meta.