# Tag filters have no tolerance for diacritics et al

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

If I create a [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) that looks for the [eleição tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o) on meta.pt.SO, it should return some questions, since they exist:

[image: result count for the eleição tag on meta.pt.SO]

The tag filter setup form disagrees, suggesting there's 0 questions with that tag:

[image: tag filter setup for the eleição tag]

If the questions had been posted more recently we might have been able to [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com), but the problem is actually that the tag filter functionality is unaware that [Marc put in all that hard work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags/135955#135955) supporting diacritics and non-Latin characters in tags, and just strips them all out:

[image: eleição tag changed to eleicao]

For kicks I tried adding the [грамматика tag](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) from Russian Language—that fails entirely with an internal server error, presumably because it can't reduce the tag name to a non-zero amount of Latin characters, which in turn trips up the rest of the process.

"Tag filters aren't a highly used feature anyway" might be a reasonable response to this, but unfortunately I really kind of need the tag filter to work correctly to automatically pull election information for the [Election Statistics site](http://elections.stackexchange.com) as there isn't another sane way to get notified of a new election*.

<sup>*In lieu of fixing this I will accept some other way of getting a list of active elections, since parsing the RSS feed is itself kind of obnoxious</sup>

Comment: I suppose you can look for `eleicao` as a workaround, until the bug gets fixed. Just don't rely on that bug forever — I wouldn't want to endorse that a search for `eleição` would to  match `eleicao` or vice versa!

Comment: In this instance I'll just add the election manually, since that's all I track the RSS feed for and I know it's started. Then it's just a matter of hoping that it's fixed before they (or another non-English site) have their next election.

Comment: Related: while the search engine on pt.so supports ignoring diacritics (e.g. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=eleicao), it does not work when you search for `[tag]`  (e.g. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beleicao%5D+eleicao). Maybe both issues could be fixed at once.

Comment: Hi, can you also give a look on this? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5175/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Yeah, I will address that, thanks!