# Can we use [tag:] for tags with non-English characters?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, markdown

In Spanish Language we have many tags with accents. For example, [*solicitud-de-término*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%C3%A9rmino).

I was writing a post in the Meta of that site and wanted to mention that tag, so I wrote:

```
[tag:solicitud-de-término]
```

However, it did not get rendered and shows a literal `[tag:solicitud-de-término]`.

Currently I am creating tag synonyms without the accents, but it doesn't seem to be useful to generate such amount of data.

Since tags to accept such characters, could you also support using them in the `[tag:XX]` markdown thingy?

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel . This is indeed related, but not the same: we do have support for them, only that there is no support in the markdown. I just checked in [French L&U](http://french.stackexchange.com/) and they do have, so `[tag:étymologie]` was displayed properly.

Comment: At the moment it looks like this works on "the-site", and doesn't work on "meta.the-site" (proof, for people who can see deleted posts: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17569/6812) - I will see if I can find out why

Comment: Note: please don't go creating synonyms for this, unless they would be valid in the first place...

Comment: @MarcGravell OK, sorry for that. I had created one (`frases-idiomaticas`) but I just removed it. Thanks for checking this!

Comment: @MarcGravell could you have a look at this? Currently it still does not show properly: [example](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674).

Comment: Sorry about that, [it's fixed now](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2546/7103)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered [a related question in the Meta Spanish site](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2546/7103) but I post it here too for completeness:

We have a per-site setting that tells whether non-ASCII characters are supposed to appear in tags or not, it was (mistakenly) set to "no" in that site. It's fixed now.

Comment: I am curious after all the process: I opened this question, got some comments by a developer and then I had to open a bounty, open the same question in Spanish's Meta and ping a couple devs more to get it solved. Shouldn't there be easier ways to get attention to a topic if it was this easy to fix? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe you did get attention, but not priority :) .

Comment: @PatrickHofman then there should be a way to know if it is `status-work-in-progress`, because otherwise it looked `status-forgotten` : )

Comment: I think there was a feature request to add some more progress insight on status tags.